# Vim cursor setup

Tags: vim

Let's say I have this line in Vim and I click `$` to reach EOL.

```
Hello Worl*d
```

The asterisk marks the place of the cursor, i.e. [image]

Let's say now that I wanted to delete backwards until the space, so I use `dT<Space>`. This leaves me with:

```
Hello *d
```

The problem is that the cursor is actually between the `l` and the `d`.

Another option in this case would `diw` (or `diW` if the *word* contained hyphens etc), but I like to be able to use the motion that first pops up in my head, and sometimes it's more obvious to do a motion until a character.

Is there any workaround here? One idea is to have the cursor moved to the right of the cursor block, instead of the left. I haven't found anything on this.

Comment: Where do you see a `/`?

Comment: Not slash, I cursivated the l and d in World. I fix it so we avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the problem is to delete the last word in the line when the EOL
character immediately follows this word, when your preferred shortcut leaves
the last character without deleting it.

The problem might be because Vim makes a distinction between inclusive and exclusive
motions. Using `v` toggles the "inclusiveness" or "exclusiveness" of a motion.

So you may use this combination:
<kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

See `:help inclusive` for an explication.

If this is too long, you may record a
[macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros)
for it.

You could also use the following shortcuts:

```
daw : delete the word under the cursor (includes spaces before the next word)
caw : same and puts you in insert mode 
diw : delete entire word without touching whitespace around it
daW : delete all characters between two whitespaces
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Will use the `v` command a lot, for sure. Thanks for the options as well.

Answer (score 1):

- With `:set virtualedit=onemore`, you can move the cursor to the right of the last character, and your command would work: `$ldT<Space>`
- As you've mentioned, the natural motion would be `iw` in this case.
- Instead of `T<Space>`, you could also use `b` here.
- I probably would use `bD` here.
- If `dT<Space>` is what first comes to your mind, you can correct the missed character with `x`. As long as you don't use the deleted contents or undo, this doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the possible solutions, I read up some one "onemore" and it seems that it may break some plugins etc, so I'll opt for the solution to [toggle `v`inclusiveness](https://superuser.com/a/1400075/986363).